# Build Gradle app "< " syntax error start up failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have never edited the build gradle files, and sunddenly, my app don't run, because doesn't sync with gradle files, specifically build gradle app. and what happens is that in the first error crashes, but opening the file, there is a lot of apparently syntax error, like structure of code, "< > " expressions... And I have never edited the file so I don't know how I supposed to change the file.. All the files that I had built was very different and this one, maded automatice way, I dont know how to change, please someone help me, is a app for a client.

CODE BUILD GRADLE (APP) (what is inside the parentesis appear red flag)

`

```
*

(<) ? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?( )>
            (<) root >
            (<) item name = "java.lang.reflect.Constructor T newInstance(java.lang.Object...)" >
            (<) annotation name = "android.support.annotation.NonNull" /( )>
            < /item>
      <item name="java.lang.reflect.Member int getModifiers()">
        <annotation name="android.support.annotation.IntDef">
          <val name="value" val="{java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PUBLIC, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PRIVATE, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PROTECTED, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.STATIC, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.FINAL, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.SYNCHRONIZED, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.VOLATILE, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.NATIVE, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.INTERFACE, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.ABSTRACT, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.STRICT}" / >
            (<) val name = "flag" val = "true" /( )>
            (<) /annotation>
      </ item >
            (<) item name = "java.lang.reflect.Proxy java.lang.Object newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class&lt;?&gt;[], java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)" >
            (<) annotation name = "android.support.annotation.NonNull" /( )>
            (<) /item>
    </ root

    dependencies {
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:+'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:+'
    }
```

*

`

------------> ERROR in all must of the cases ->  expected got "<"

-----------> In the Event Log

14:44   Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
            build file 'C:\Users\Andre\Videos\Gelitos2\app\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
            < ? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ? >
            ^
            1 error
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2 m 21 s 996 ms)

---

I had already tryed to edit apparently over spaces and missing close tags ">", but nothing worked
I also tried to invalidate caches and restart
I tried to shutdown the pc

And I also tried do Clean the project but others errors msgs, a lot appears, and all because a file that I have never edited. This is what shows:

When I clean this shows

Comment: Hi Andre, why you have put XML stuff in your  build.gradle

Comment: Hi, thank you, Exactly! I found out serious  problems with my keyboard and mouse, so probly They cut and paste when I wasn't seeing!

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Andre Biriba Teixeira,

Remove this part from your gradle --

> (<) ? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?( )>
>               (<) root >
>               (<) item name = "java.lang.reflect.Constructor T newInstance(java.lang.Object...)" >
>               (<) annotation name = "android.support.annotation.NonNull" /( )>
>               < /item>
>         
>           
>             
>               (<) val name = "flag" val = "true" /( )>
>               (<) /annotation>
>         
>               (<) item name = "java.lang.reflect.Proxy java.lang.Object newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class<?>[],
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)" >
>               (<) annotation name = "android.support.annotation.NonNull" /( )>
>               (<) /item>

and try gradle sync again.

Comment: Hey @adre, thats great. Can you please accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: The answer is to rewrite all the file from previous backup, this code is all wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found out serious  problems with my keyboard and mouse, so probly They cut and paste when I wasn't seeing!
I reeopen a backup and copied the previous codes in the build files, thanks everyone.